# Angular ng-messages, errors, warnings and form validity

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

Is there a angular (1.4+) way with ng-messages to show warnings and errors the difference being that warnings don't make the form invalid but the errors do so the user can save the form even though there are warnings?
Searched all over and can't seem to find anything about this though I think it should be an obvious part of the system o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the [Ng-Messages Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) I don't believe that is possible.

When you include the `ng-messages` onto an html element they will hide or show that element based on the $error object in the form field. You can create custom errors if you like, but if triggered they will always make the form invalid.

To get around this you could write something to watch a user's input and have a bootstrap warning message set to conditionally appear if the conditions are met, but not have that be in any `ng-messages` html element.

Comment: I think you would still want errors to make the form invalid, just have a separate div or whatever to display alerts with ugly `ng-if` directives

Comment: Yes I will use $error for true errors but ng-if for warnings even though it is a "dirty" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, by monkey-patching object that you are listening in  ng-messages and show corresponding message when your custom property changed.